# NodeJS Cloudinary Upload Video

Tags: node.js, video, upload, cloudinary

Here is cloudinary documentation page.
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_videos#uploading_from_server_side_code

According to doc, video uploading like the following code.

```
var videoFile = req.files.video.path;    
cloudinary.uploader.upload(videoFile,
                function(result) {console.log(result); },
                { resource_type: "video" });
```

Also, it supports none image file upload like that.

```
var videoFile = req.files.video.path;
cloudinary.uploader.upload(videoFile,
                function(result) {console.log(result); },
                { resource_type: "raw" });
```

Also my html file:

```
<form action="/videos/add" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    <div class="form_line">
                        <label for="video_title">Title:</label>
                        <div class="form_controls">
                            <input id="video_title" name="title" size="30" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_line">
                        <label for="video">Video:</label>
                        <div class="form_controls">
                            <input id="video" name="video" type="file" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_line">
                        <div class="form_controls">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit Video</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input id="direct" name="direct" type="hidden" />
                </form>
```

I am getting error for the both code even I specify the resource type.

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid image file"}}
```

https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/issues/26

[Upload video to Cloudinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797546/upload-video-to-cloudinary)

How can I solve this issue ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can also upload the video in chunks this is very suitable for large files.

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload_large(file, 
            function(result) {console.log(result); }, 
            { resource_type: "video" });

    v1_result_adapter = function(callback) {
 if (callback != null) {
 return function(result) { if (result.error != null) { 
callback(result.error); return;} else { callback(void 0, result); return; } }; } else { return null; } };
```

Comment: node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils.js:1028
          return callback(void 0, result); TypeError: callback is not a function . I think some issue about the library but I can't figure out.

Comment: The full code is in the question. But   here is the problem.                                   `v1_result_adapter = function(callback) {
    if (callback != null) {
      return function(result) {
        if (result.error != null) {
          return callback(result.error);
        } else {
          return callback(void 0, result);
        }
      };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };`

Comment: it's because you are not passing callback everytime.

Comment: This is not my code. Here is the library. https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/master/lib/utils.js line 1022

Comment: The code you shared:

`cloudinary.uploader.upload(videoFile,
                function(result) {console.log(result); },
                { resource_type: "video" });`

Should work fine for videos. 

Are you getting an 'Invalid image file' error when running it?

Comment: Nope. Video file json data is coming but I can't pass v1_result_adapter function because of TypeError but I try it again.

Comment: Yes, I am getting "Invalid image file" when I use cloudinary.uploader.upload. But when I use cloudinary.uploader.upload_large, v1_result_adapter function taken result as https://jsonblob.com/ba322512-d7f0-11e6-b16a-7d99b2ab453d then TypeError.

Comment: 'Invalid image file' error is raised when you try to upload a resource which isn't an image (`resource_type` is defaulted to image). Using `resource_type` should help - set `video` if you want to upload a video file or `raw` for files that are niether video or image. This works perfect on my end, so please check your code again.

Comment: Hı, I am setting resource_type as a video, raw, auto and my code is not working."TypeError: callback is not a function" error still continues. Do you have any suggestion to fix it ?

Comment: Hı, I solved my problem.  Here is the link. (https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/issues/129)

Answer (score 0):

This code work 100%

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload_large(
  lecturePath,
  function (result) {
    console.log(result.secure_url);
    const lecture = {
      title,
      description,
      video: result.secure_url,
    };
  },
  { resource_type: "video" }
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).